# How do I avoid an image being overwritten to blank when user edit their profile?

Tags: php, html, mysql, image, updates

I have an issue with my website. I'm using PHP and MYSQL.

1. A user click on update profile page, it redirects to edit profile page.
2. There's an  for user to upload their image. Default value is blank even the user already has    a picture uploaded to the database.
3. If user click on update, the image on the Database will be overwritten to blank.
4. On user's profile page, their old image will be overwritten to blank.

Below is my html code to upload the image in profileedit:

```
<label style="padding-left:3em"> Image: </label> <input type="file" name="image" id="image" value=""> </input>
```

And my PHP script looks like below:

```
mysqli_query("UPDATE people SET Image='$image' WHERE id=".$_GET['id']);
```

**Please help !**

Comment: Don't update on blank, have a dedicated button to delete the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check if there is a new image:

```
 if (!empty($image)) {
     mysqli_query("UPDATE people SET Image='$image' WHERE id=".$_GET['id']);
 }
```